# Error at showing more and less javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two tables that I need show more and less feature. I have built using javascript, it's working fine when I clicked show more and less on one table, but when show more on table 1 and table 2 clicked simultaneously, I need to clicked show less two or three times to get back before.

Here's the js script

```
$(function () {

x=6;
$('#table1 li').slice(0, 6).show();
$('#showLess').hide();
$('#table2 li').slice(0, 6).show();
$('#less').hide();
$('#loadMore').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x+7;
    $('#table1 li').slice(0, x).slideDown();
    $('#showLess').show();
    $('#loadMore').hide();
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    x=(x-7<0) ? 6 : x-7;
    $('#table1 li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();

    $('#showLess').hide();
    $('#loadMore').show();
    if(x = 6){
        $('#showLess').hide();
    }
});
$('#more').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    x = x+7;
    $('#table2 li').slice(0, x).slideDown();
    $('#less').show();
    $('#more').hide();
});
$('#less').click(function () {
    x=(x-7<0) ? 6 : x-7;
    $('#table2 li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();

    $('#less').hide();
    $('#more').show();
    if(x = 6){
        $('#less').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Here's html code

```
<style>
   #table1 li{
        display:none;
   }
   #table2 li{
     display:none;
   }
  </style>


<ul id="table1">                                                     
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; One</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Two</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Three</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Four</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Five</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Six</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Seven</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Eight</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Nine</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Ten</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Eleven</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Twelve</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Thirteen</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">More</div>
<div id="showLess">Less</div>

<ul id="table2">                                                     
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; One</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Two</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Three</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Four</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Five</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Six</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Seven</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Eight</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Nine</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Ten</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Eleven</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Twelve</li>
   <li style="text-align:left">- &nbsp; Thirteen</li>
</ul>
<div id="more">More</div>
<div id="less">Less</div>
```

Do you know where's the error from the code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

I need to give another different variable name, like a and b. The error because I only put same variable name on two conditions